# Put content of private key as argument in jenkins cli

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to pass content of private key as argument in jenkins cli:

```
java jar jenkins_cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 groovy users.groovy "username" "password" "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEpgIBAAK....."
```

But got error:

```
"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEpgIBAAKCAQEA6jyLIA7wX5rTABArKe6dqTA1vpjRmB3MQnnqDsjMbS9NKCDl nWKDtK9E+xyObr7amP9QV+iCBA26KGy7Zboae6zvAZpCywqfMENaO5lWkRishYOx..." is not valid option
```

And getting help after this error.

How can I escape this argument which begins from "----". Execute it on bash. Thank you!

Comment: That's no longer a private key. You should pass the *name* of the private key file, and make sure the file (with appropriate permissions) is available in the runtime environment.

Comment: But what if I want to enter directly this key for credentials plugin?

Comment: Question is not very clear.  You are running a "command line".  Does passing it with single quote help?

Comment: it's a jenkins cli issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30652